# Can i group documents by using lookup column with multiple value?

Tags: lookup-column, groups, grouping, multiple-values

One document belongs to many row. It is allowed . But I want to group them and show the document on each group. Is it possible ?

Comment: Please can you provide more details ? I can't understand your requirement.

Comment: I added lookup column. And enabled "Allow multiple values " . And now i can add more rows to my document. But i could not group them by lookup. Because it has got multiple variables. So how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **LIBRARY** in the ribbon.
2. Click on **Modify View**.
3. Scroll down to **Group By** section.
4. Select the column you aim to group it by.

Comment: But when i enabled "Allow multiple values " section, i did not see lookup column on dropdown list ?

Comment: It's not possible to Group a **Lookup column** with **Multiple value**.

Comment: So any advice? Can i do this with code or query or other web part?

Comment: You can do it by XML in your list using Viusal Studio but you will get an **illogical grouping** things that is expected so the only  way is to create a **lookup column without Multiple value**.